What algorithm can compute the eigenvectors when eigenvalues are already known?
Suppose eigenvalues for a matrix has been found previously.
There is a human-friendly way to solve for the eigenvectors, for example,

How can the above "human algorithm" be programmed on a machine to solve for the eigenvectors?

For each eigenvalue $\lambda$ you want to compute $\ker(A - \lambda)$ so the problem reduces to solving a system of linear equations. My understanding is that this is an extremely fundamental computational task so there should be very fast and highly optimized algorithms available for doing it. If you want to do it yourself you can figure out how to code row reduction.

@QiaochuYuan thank you. I have coded the row reduction, and my problem is actually at the trial-and-error like problem solving after the row reduction is completed... "Well, since the second row entries are all 0, we know that x2 is a free variable. From equation 1, we have -7x1 + 2x2 = 0,  etc..." Any ideas how can this part of the solver be written as an algorithm (for large 100x100+ matrices)?

If you are given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and an eigenvalue of that matrix $\lambda$, the matrix $M = A-\lambda I$ will have a non-zero nullspace.  Any vector in that nullspace is an eigenvector for $\lambda$.  You can compute these explicitly using Gaussian Elimination (ie. row reduction).  Doing row-reduction operations on $M$ will put it in the following form (assuming the first columns become the pivot columns).
$$
M \substack{\rightarrow \\ \text{row} \\ \text{-reduce}}
\begin{bmatrix}
I & B \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $B \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-k)\times k}$ where $k$ is the dimension of the eigensubspace corresponding to $\lambda$. (Note that for a simple problem, where there is only a 1-dim subspace associated with $\lambda$, $ B \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-1)\times 1}$.  Now consider the matrix
$$
N = \begin{bmatrix} B \\ - I \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}
$$
Any column of $N$ is in the nullspace of $M$ and is thus an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $\lambda$.  (More generally, the columns of $N$ actually form a basis for the eigenspace of $\lambda$, ie. any eigenvector (for $\lambda$) can be written as $x = Nz$ for some $z \in \mathbb{R}^k$. More thorough details for the general case can be found on wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra))
If you do the row-reduction operation and the pivot columns do not come first then you can still use this method; you just need to do an extra step with a permutation matrix. The general statement is that for any matrix $M$ of the form above, there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that
$$
MP \substack{\rightarrow \\ \text{row} \\ \text{-reduce}} \begin{bmatrix} I & B \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
The permutation matrix here is a simple matrix of 1's & 0's (details here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).  $MP$ simply shuffles the order of the columns of $M$ (so that the pivot columns come first). (Try this with a simple example and you will see how.)  In this general case, we now have that $N = \begin{bmatrix} B \\ -I \end{bmatrix}$ defines vectors in the nullspace of $MP$.  If we want to now compute vectors in the nullspace of $M$, we can note the following:  $MP\times N = 0$ implies  $M \times PN = 0$ and thus the columns of $PN$ are in the nullspace of $M$ and define eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$. ($PN$ shuffles the rows of $N$ similar to the way $MP$ shuffles the columns of $M$.)
